# Relation between push forward by diagonal morphism and higher direct image functors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, derived-functors, abstract-nonsense, pushforward

Let $f : X \to Y$ be a morphism between two Noetherian schemes. Then  $f_*$(respect to $R^1f_*$) sends coherent sheaves to coherent sheaves if and only if $f$ is universally closed (respect to separated) according to the answer of [If the direct image of f preserves coherent sheaves on noetherian schemes, how to show f is proper?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/180865/if-the-direct-image-of-f-preserves-coherent-sheaves-on-noetherian-schemes-how-t?fbclid=IwAR0-OLiexwMhOGgUCrdIYWnr9j19tcPSDshm6sVFlXGuUlgiAXoPvNVxt3o)

Since $f$ is separated if and only if its diagonal morphism $\Delta_f$ is universally closed, I wonder if there exists any direct relation between $R^1f_*$ and $(\Delta_f)_*$.
Also, can we generalize relation between two functors in the case of quasi separated & quasi compact morphism?